# What is the accuracy of an iBeacon

Tags: objective-c, ibeacon

I can't really understand what `accuracy` means, I know that `proxymity` is a range of the iBeacon (immediate, near, far, unknown) based on the strenght of the signal, but what about `accuracy`?
The doc says

> The accuracy of the proximity value, measured in meters from the
>   beacon

So does it mean that it's a value that says how much meters you're away from the iBeacon or it's just a value that tells you if you're close to one of the `proximity` zones?

Comment: Its probably similar to GPS accuracy. Given whatever factors they take into account, the accuracy is a circle with a radius of n(accuracy) meters that the beacon is in. It defines the percentage error.

Comment: ok but I can't understand if i should use accuracy or proximity to check whenever I enter in range of a beacon, because proximity has 3 values to check (immediate 0-1m, near 1-3m, far 3-70m) but I'd like to change that

Comment: You'll probably need to check both. If accuracy is low (a high number if it works like GPS accuracy), you may not want to rely on the proximity readings. If the proximity reading says that the beacon is 2m away, but your accuracy readings says it could be anywhere in a 10m radius, I wouldn't trust the proximity reading; somethings throwing it off. Both numbers are probably just guesses by some algorithm; you should take both into consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Accuracy is an estimate of the distance in meters to the beacon.**  This is only a very rough estimate based on Bluetooth signal strength (RSSI) and varies quite a bit due to radio noise.

Due to the error, Apple recommends it be used only to determine the relative positions of beacons when multiple are visible.

You can read more about how this works here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html

Comment: ok thanks a lot! 
One last question if possible, so what do you suggest me to use in order to know when I enter in a specific beacon range? for example i just need to know when I enter 5/10 meter near the beacon

Comment: Look at distance and accuracy and draw your conclusion. There is no hard rule. Test the behaviour with a real beacon in the wild and see if it behaves the way you want.

Comment: You simply call `startRangingBeaconsInRegion:` and then in the `didRangeBacons:inRegion:`  callback, iterate through the `beacons` array to look for one where `beacon.accuracy < 5`.  Just know that this isn't perfect and this logic may trigger when thw mobile device is 10 meters away or not until it is 2 meters away.  Be sure to set expectations properly.